# Http empty response with PHP

Tags: php, apache, http, curl

I have a big trouble here in my hands. Randomly my server starts returning no buffer from my PHP files. I mean, I access somefile.php, and then I do some things in the system, when I try to access somefile.php again I suddenly got a **ERR_EMPTY RESPONSE** (in the browser).

I have already tried in all browsers. Same thing. When I ask to anyone else access the same file in a different machine, it goes ok, but in my machine, I still seeing the error. So I have decided to do a cURL request in the page and see what's going on, the result is below.

**With the following code:**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://192.168.1.15/curiaonline/projetobase/paroquialogada.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
?>
```

**I got:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 Jun 2015 20:41:59 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.12
Content-Length: 7
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

hy test"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.1.15...
* Connected to 192.168.1.15 (192.168.1.15) port 80 (#0)
> POST /curiaonline/projetobase/paroquialogada.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.15
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 16 Jun 2015 20:41:59 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.12
< Content-Length: 7
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

and then I change the **CURLOPT_POST** to **FALSE** I got:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.1.15...
* Connected to 192.168.1.15 (192.168.1.15) port 80 (#0)
> GET /curiaonline/projetobase/paroquialogada.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.15
Accept: */*

* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.15 left intact
```

The paroquialogada.php file only contains "hy test".

**I have already tried:**

- To disable my firewall
- To disable server firewall
- To search for errors in PHP error log
- To search for errors in Apache error log
- To clean my dns cache
- To renew my windows connection

Comment: maybe you should buy new pc  : )

Comment: this is just local host? are you going to host this elsewhere?

Comment: the page is obviously looking for a `POST` command and if that is not the request type its not returning anything, you need to post the code for the page in question to help troubleshoot it.

Comment: @Dagon This is our server tests, The same problem happens in the production server randomly with random clients.

Comment: @cmorrissey, this is strange, because the page is working fine, and then suddenly starts to send no data to the connection client. Nobody changes nothing to make a behavior change.

Comment: @Dagon, as I have sayd, there is no PHP code in the file. There was, but I removed some parts of the code to search for the error, no change in the response. I have removed all code, no change. I have put the "hy test" message in the file, nothing changed.

Answer (score 3):

**I have found the problem.** It was the security software for internet banking that I have to use to access my account, since I'm a **Banco do Brasil's** customer. This software provided by **GAS Tecnologia** see chrome request as viruses, and block the responses from the server in Windows. Anyone who have a likely problem, and use Internet Banking, just disable this software.

Comment: This was the problem for me as well. I'm using Apache 2.2 locally on my Mac (OSX 10.11), PHP 5.6. Turning off Avast’s ‘web shield’ (antivirus software) fixed the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE problem.

Comment: Same issue with bitdefender, had to add the domain to exclusions.

Answer (score 0):

> and then I change the `CURLOPT_POST to FALSE` I got:

If page content requires **POST** to handle request. Every request must with **POST** request.

for example assume a page which has like below

```
if( isset($_POST["blabla"]) ){
 //then do something
}
```

if part works only with POST, so consider this issue.

Don't refresh your page on browser. Submit necessary values with **POST**.

Comment: No, I don't think so, take a look: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dcc0a7b2961df4f338fd